# Error: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

> Error: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint
>   fails?
>       (`testlogin`.`leavetable`, CONSTRAINT `leavetable_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY
>       (`users_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)

Been getting this message for the last day and a half. Trying to make a one to many (foreign key) relationship between the two tables. Between `users:id` and `leavetable:users_id`. When user logs in they get a id. when they submit a form to column `hours` I'd like for the id to stay with the form data. It is throwing the error when someone creates a new id number and it wont update the `leavetable:user_id`. It throws the error above.

Here's my code:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` ( 
`email` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL, 
`id` int(11) NOT NULL, 
`password` char(64) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL, 
`salt` char(16) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL, 
`username` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL 
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1; 



CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `leavetable` ( 
`hours` int(11) NOT NULL, 
`users_id` int(11) DEFAULT NOT NULL, 
`id` int(11) NOT NULL 
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1; 


 ALTER TABLE `users` 
 ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`) USING BTREE, 
 ADD UNIQUE KEY `email` (`email`) USING BTREE, 
 ADD UNIQUE KEY `username` (`username`) USING BTREE; 

 ALTER TABLE `leavetable` 
 ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`) USING BTREE, 
 ADD KEY `users_id` (`users_id`) USING BTREE; 

 ALTER TABLE `leavetable` 
 MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT; 
 -- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `users` 
 ALTER TABLE `users` 
 MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT; 

ALTER TABLE `leavetable` 
ADD CONSTRAINT `leavetable_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`users_id`) REFERENCES
`users` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

my table structure:

```
+---------------------+
| Tables_in_testlogin |
+---------------------+
| leavetable          |
| users               |
+---------------------+

+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field    | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| email    | varchar(255) | NO   | UNI | NULL    |                |
| id       | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| password | char(64)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| salt     | char(16)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| username | varchar(255) | NO   | UNI | NULL    |                |
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
5 rows in set (0.01 sec)

+----------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field    | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| hours    | int(11) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| users_id | int(11) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| id       | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
+----------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
3 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

Comment: If it is on an update stmt, or an insert, and the FK is in place, then the action violates the FK constraint. `leavetable.user_id` does not exist in `users`

Comment: how can I make it update when a new user is registered. I just changed that a little bit ago. It was named `leavetable.id` but it didn't matter.

Comment: can you merely show us the end result of the two tables, with `show create table users` and `show create table leavetable`

Comment: insert the new user on an `autoincrement` hopefully. You get the last insert id, and use that with references to `leavetable` ... php session variable usage would be an idea to think about

Comment: PDO would be [this](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php), mysqli would be [this](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php)

Comment: They both start with no data and then when someone registers and goes to the page with the form the error above is on the page.

Comment: I guess I sorta understand that. But when they register, you have the user id in a session variable. Then anytime you put a new row in a table for that session, there is no reason that the FK would fail if that variable value is provided to insert/update, no ?

Answer (score 1):

**First you have to clean sub table's data then clear foreign key between mastertable after that you can clear any data**